# Need to change the encoding format based on one of the XML tags

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am using XSL style sheet and XML to generate a text output. I need to pass one of the XML tag values to the encoding format but couldn't find the syntax. Can you please help?

I tried to store the XML in the variable as shown in my code but it is not working

XSL Stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" extension-element-prefixes="exsl"> 
<xsl:variable name="encoding1" select="NAME/ENCODING"/>
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="encoding1" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
```

XML data:

```
 <NAME>
  <ENCODING>us-ascii</ENCODING>
  <PRESCRIPTION>200</PRESCRIPTION>
 </NAME>
```

Expected: txt file with encoding format as ANSI
Actual: unable to merge both XML and stylesheet

Answer (score 2):

The element `xsl:output` does not support an `xsl:variable` as input to the `encoding` attribute. But you can use the XSLT-2.0 element `xsl:result-document` with attribute-value-templates to circumvent that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"> 
<xsl:variable name="encoding1" select="/NAME/ENCODING"/>
<xsl:variable name="inputFileName"  select="'input.xml'"/>
<xsl:variable name="outputFileName" select="'result.xml'"/>

    <!-- Identity template for 'input' -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="input">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="input" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 

    <!-- Create the result document with the desired encoding - here the input XML is copied -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:message terminate="no">Encoding is: <xsl:value-of select="$encoding1" /></xsl:message>
        <xsl:result-document encoding="{$encoding1}" href="{$outputFileName}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="document($inputFileName)" mode="input" />
        </xsl:result-document>    
    </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here, the input document `input.xml` is copied with the new encoding specified in the XML document passed as parameter (which contains the `/NAME/ENCODING`) to the XSLT processor.

Comment: Can you please clarify how will be the format if we are using a merging tool to merge XML and XSL instead of passing the input? I tried the below code but the encoding is not working.                                                                                                                           <xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:result-document encoding="{$encoding1}" method="text">
    <MY CODE>
</xsl:result-document>

Comment: First, to get _text_ output, add a `method="text"` attribute to the `xsl:result-document` like you would do to an `xsl:output`element. Second: I do not get the point of "merging the XML and XSLT". This seems to be a strange idea and pretty useless, so I guess that you do mean something else. So what is `<MY CODE>` supposed to mean in a greater sense? The current state of the code is: one file for XSLT, one file naming the encoding and one file for the data whose encoding should be changed (and should be output as text).

Comment: If you'd change the value of the `inputFileName` variable to the same as the input file of your stylesheet, you'd transform your input XML data to the new encoding defined in itself (the same file). This would be a fascinating way to change the encoding of a file.